# Unable to add condition colouring to a text in the adaptive card

Tags: node.js, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I have a bot which generates adaptive cards into the channel.

I am trying to add colour to the text using conditions.

```
{
        "type": "AdaptiveCard",
        "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
        "version": "1.3",
        "body": [
            {
                "type": "TextBlock",
                "size": "Medium",
                "weight": "Bolder",
                "text": "${title}",
                "color": "${if(10 >= 0, 'good', 'attention')}"
            }
        ]
}
```

**Error**

```
"error": {
    "code": "BadSyntax",
    "message": "Failed to read card payload as JSON"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So, after scrolling through the web and with the help of this issue https://github.com/microsoft/AdaptiveCards/issues/7040

We first need to install **Adaptive Card Templating for JavaScript** library https://www.npmjs.com/package/adaptivecards-templating

**Example code:**

```
var ACData = require('adaptivecards-templating');

let cardJson = {
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.3",
    "body": [
          {
                "type": "TextBlock",
                "size": "Medium",
                "weight": "Bolder",
                "text": "${number}",
                "color": "${if(number > 0, 'good', 'attention')}"
          }
    ]
}

// crucial step
var template = new ACData.Template(cardJson);


let finalCardJson = template.expand({
        $root: {
            number: 10
        },
})
```

Then you can use `finalCardJson` to send an adaptive card in the channel or as per your use case.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By using if condition we can set the color to 'good' and 'attention'.
Example:

```
{
"type": "AdaptiveCard",
"$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
"version": "1.3",
"body": [
    {            
          "$data": "${MonthlyEfforts}",
          "type": "TextBlock",
          "weight": "bolder",
          "separator": true,
           "color": "${if(WorkedHours < 5, 'attention', 'good')}",
          "text": "Hours worked: ${WorkedHours}"
    }]
    }
```

Comment: That is exactly my card json looks like, you need to pass through the `adaptivecards-templating ` library. See my answer below